# Retrieve users top score from Game Center with swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, game-center

I need to retrieve a player's top submitted score from Game Center. I think I found the answer in objective C, but I don't know how to write it in swift since I am fairly new to this. Can someone help me translate the following code into swift? Thank you in advance.

```
GKLeaderboard *leaderboardRequest = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardRequest != nil) {
        [leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error){
            if (error != nil) {
                //Handle error
            }
            else{
                [delegate onLocalPlayerScoreReceived:leaderboardRequest.localPlayerScore];
            }
        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straight translation to Swift:

```
let leaderboardRequest = GKLeaderboard() as GKLeaderboard!
if leaderboardRequest != nil
{
    leaderboardRequest.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler({ (scores:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil
        {
            //handle error
        }
        else
        {
            delegate.onLocalPlayerScoreReceived(leaderboardRequest.localPlayerScore)
        }
    })
}
```